# C# grouping strings start with the same numbers

Tags: c#, group-by

I am getting file names from the directory like this:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Maps\", "*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

And it brings the file names like this:

```
11_page1.txt
11_page2.txt
11_page3.txt
11_page4.txt
11_page5.txt

12_page9.txt
12_page10.txt
12_page11.txt
12_page23.txt

13_page46.txt
13_page50.txt
13_page51.txt
```

I want to group the file names by the numbers which are located that first part of the file names like 11, 12, 13.

I have any idea.

I searched in the site but I can not find any suitable solution.

Comment: You can get the numeric part using `string.Split`. You can then group on that like you would group anything else. Use some logic and think about how you would do it manually, then write code to implement that. Don't just assume that programming is finding code to copy and paste on the web. It's thinking about and implementing logic. If you want to do it using LINQ then learn about LINQ grouping first, then do the split I specified and group on that. If you haven't tried then you haven't failed and if you haven't failed then you have no question to ask here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> fileNames = new List<string>
        {
            "11_page1.txt", "11_page2.txt", "11_page3.txt", "11_page4.txt", "11_page5.txt",
            "12_page9.txt", "12_page10.txt", "12_page11.txt", "12_page23.txt",
            "13_page46.txt", "13_page50.txt", "13_page51.txt"
        };

        var groupedFileNames = fileNames
            .Select(fileName => new
            {
                FileName = fileName,
                Prefix = GetNumberPrefix(fileName)
            })
            .GroupBy(x => x.Prefix)
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(x => x.FileName).ToList());

        foreach (var group in groupedFileNames)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Group {group.Key}:");
            foreach (string fileName in group.Value)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"  {fileName}");
            }
        }
    }

    static string GetNumberPrefix(string fileName)
    {
        Match match = Regex.Match(fileName, @"^(\d+)");
        if (match.Success)
        {
            return match.Groups[1].Value;
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `Linq`, you can group using a `GroupBy` and result in a dictionary:

```
var dico = files.GroupBy(x => x.Split('_').First())
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToArray());
```

Each string key has its array of filename.

If you want the key numeric:

```
var dico = files.GroupBy(x => x.Split('_').First())
                .ToDictionary(x => int.Parse(x.Key), x => x.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 2):

---

To group the file names by the numbers located in the first part of the file names, you can use LINQ to group the files based on the first two characters of the file name. Here's an example code snippet that should do what you need:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Maps\", "*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

var groupedFiles = files.GroupBy(f => f.Substring(0, 2));

foreach (var group in groupedFiles)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Files starting with {group.Key}:");
    foreach (var file in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\t{file}");
    }
}
```